# Editing Footer Information

Tags: theme-development

I just built a theme for a client. I am wondering what is the best way to make footer content editable through Wordpress. The footer info looks like this:

- Company Name
- Address Line 1
- Address Line 2
- Phone and Fax
- Email (linked with mailto)

I have some ideas on how to do this:

1. Make a page called footer and grab the content from there.
2. Widgetize the footer and make it a text widget
3. Make a themes option panel with the option to customize this text

I would love to know what you guys think is your best solution to this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with a Widgetized footer.

If you want to go the extra mile, rather than create Theme Options, simply create a custom Widget, e.g. Footer Contact Details, that has editable text inputs for Company Name, Address Lines 1 and 2, Phone/Fax, and Email.